# Import org.apache.chemistry cannot be resolved, but library is already in build path?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

Eclipse can't seem to locate org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.chemistry-opencmis-osgi-client_x.y.z.jar. I've tried adding it to every possible location. What am I missing?

[image: code and workspace]
[image: build path]

It's not mentioned in pom.xml, but that shouldn't be required according to the tutorial I'm following.

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshot I can see that you already have Maven, because I see your pom.xml file. If you have Maven please install this dependency manually.
Maybe this like can help you [How to add a local jar in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project)
I would add this dependency in POM and install this JAR manually. If your company has a Nexus, I would later upload it there.